# How to connect to remote (docker) kernel using SSH (Spyder)

Tags: python, docker, spyder

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update && apt install  openssh-server sudo -y

run apt-get update
run apt-get install python3
run apt-get -y install python3-pip
run pip install spyder-kernels

RUN echo "root:password" | chpasswd

RUN service ssh start

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

I have built it using `docker build -t spyder`. The I run it using `docker run -d -p 2000:22 --name spyder_container spyder`. Next I typed `docker exec -it spyder_container /bin/bash` and I launched kernel by typing  `python3 -m spyder_kernels.console`. Next I copied the json kernel file using the following in new powershell window:

```
 docker cp spyder_container:/root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-16.json Desktop
```

The file looks like this:

```
{
  "shell_port": 35431,
  "iopub_port": 40443,
  "stdin_port": 35379,
  "control_port": 39321,
  "hb_port": 38567,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "29a176a0-15b65a765ce1568ad69ebbbe",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

Finally in Spyder is filled the windows as follows (password is "password"):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGmA0.png)

but it cannot connect :( What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I tried to log into container using `docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" spyder_container` first to find IP and then `ssh root@172.17.0.6` but it doesnt work due to `ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.6 port 22: Connection timed out` :( I also added

```
RUN sed -i '/^#/!s/PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sudo service ssh restart
```

to dockerfile

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spyder, but my guess is that you need to put port 2000 in the window you've taken a screenshot of.

Comment: Doesnt work too :(

Comment: Can you set your image to run, say, `CMD python3 -m spyder_kernels.console`, without bothering with the hard-to-secure sshd setup or a `docker exec` debugging shell?